# Create global variable in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgresql-9.1

I am creating trigger for log table. In that trigger i want to store `xuserno` to log table. `xuserno` is a argument of all function

example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_consume(xmode text, xuserno integer)
  RETURNS text AS
....
.....
.....

END;
```

`Each table` have this type of `function`. So how can i access the `xuserno` in my `trigger`. How can i create `global variable` for this purpose? or any other solution is have achive this?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/13172524/398670

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use transaction-local custom GUCs for this purpose but it's not usually a great idea.

In most cases it is preferable to just use an `ON COMMIT DROP` temporary table with a single row containing the value of interest.

See:

- [Passing user id to PostgreSQL triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13172524/398670)
- [How do you use script variables in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36959/398670)

Comment: If am using like this `set myapp.user_name=xuserno';` xuserno is argument of function. Using this for get value `SELECT current_setting('myapp.user_name')` but it show `xuserno` not a ` xuserno value ` why? Are anything am doing wrong

Comment: @SATSON From the information you've given I couldn't possibly say. Post a new question with the full code of the procedure in complete, runnable form along with your PostgreSQL version etc.