# Update field updated by trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a table with multiple fields and an additional outofsync field.
Created a trigger and trigger function to set outofsync field value to true before any update/insert.

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER goods_update_outofsync
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON goods
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE tg_update_goods_outofsync();
```

Trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tg_update_goods_outofsync()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
    NEW.outofsync=true;
    RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION tg_update_goods_outofsync()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

And now comes to a "simple" question I am not able to find answer: how to update manually outofsync field to false, because after each attempt it is automatically changed to true by trigger.

EDIT:

This almost works:

```
IF (NEW.outofsync = OLD.outofsync) THEN
    NEW.outofsync=true;
END IF;
```

Except when value of outofsync field is already false and I want to set it to false, because it became true then...

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least four options:

- Set to in sync as another user and test `current_user` in the trigger;
- Define a custom config variable (GUC) and `SET LOCAL` or `set_config(...)` it in the transaction before updating the in sync field; test that GUC in the trigger and change behaviour based on it;
- Temporarily disable the trigger in the transaction before setting in sync;
- Have the trigger check if all the other values are unchanged by the update and allow in sync to be set to true if no other values have changed. Use `IS DISTINCT FROM` for this test to handle nulls conveniently.

I'd probably use a custom GUC myself, with `current_setting('my.guc')` to fetch the value from within the trigger.

If you're on Pg 9.1 or older you must add `my` (or whatever you really call the prefix) to `custom_variable_classes`. In 9.2 and above any variable with a period (`.`) in it is assumed to be a custom variable.

See also [passing user ID to triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172524/passing-user-id-to-postgresql-triggers).

Comment: Because I am not familiar with GUC and have a lot of fields in this table (for solution D), I will disable trigger I think. Thank you!

Comment: http://koo.fi/blog/2013/01/08/disable-postgresql-triggers-temporarily/ I think I would rather disable all triggers in current session than just one, but globally.

Comment: Oh, you can use the normal `set_config` SQL function instead of the `SET` statement too.