# Make trigger behavior depend on query

Tags: sql, postgresql

My goal is to make trigger behavior to depend on some client identifier.

For example I execute a query

```
begin;
<specify-some-client-identifier>
insert into some_table
values('value')
commit;
```

And I have trigger function executing before insert:

```
NEW.some_filed := some_func(<some-client-identifier-spicified-above>)
```

So, how do I `<specify-some-client-identifier>` and get `<some-client-identifier-spicified-above>`?

Comment: client-identifier?? by this variable are you planning to process for differently for eack client (sessions) or this you want to add for different - different procedure where this table is getting updated or inserted data?

Comment: @pratik, I need to differentiate sessions. Query is generated by the client.

Comment: In future please always specify your PostgreSQL version (`SELECT version()`) and try to provide some more info about what exactly you want. In this case "client" and "identifier" aren't what you'd call super-informative. Username? source IP? Some kind of cookie code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need some kind of variables in SQL. It is possible to do it, with multiple ways:

- using GUCs
- using table with variables
- using temp table with variables
- using %_SHARED in plperl functions

All this is possible. If you're interested in implementation details and/or comparison - check this [blogpost](http://www.depesz.com/2013/02/25/variables-in-sql-what-how-when/) - just in case it wasn't obvious from domain - it's my blog.

Answer (score 2):

You will find [this prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172524/passing-user-id-to-postgresql-triggers/13172964#13172964) informative. There I explain how to pass an application-defined username through so it is visible to PostgreSQL functions and triggers.

You can also use the `application_name` GUC, which can be set by most client drivers or explicitly by the application. Depending on your purposes this may be sufficient.

Finally, you can examine `pg_stat_activity` to get info about the current client by looking it up by `pg_backend_pid()`. This will give you a client IP and port if TCP/IP is being used.

Of course, there's also `current_user` if you log in as particular users at the database level.

As usual, @depesz points out useful options I hadn't thought of, too - using shared context within PL/Perl, in particular. You can do the same thing in PL/Python. In both cases you'll pay the startup overhead of a full procedural language interpreter and the function call costs of accessing it, so it probably only makes sense to do this if you're already using PL/Perl or PL/Python.