# Hooking into start of JDBC transaction

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I have a Spring Boot webapp connected to a Postgres 9.6 database.
I use Spring's `JdbcTemplate` for executing SQL statements.
Each table in my database has triggers for INSERT, CREATE and DELETE statments. These triggers copy the affected rows into a history table.

I want the triggers to also save the *application* user ID of the user who made the change.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/13172964/2591231 I can achieve my goal by having the application insert the current user id into a temporary table **at the start of each transaction** and having the triggers read from the temporary table.
A similar method, mentioned in several other places, is executing:
`SET LOCAL application_name = "my_application_user"`, then reading `application_name` inside the triggers. Again, this has to be done at the start of each transaction.

I'm looking for way, which is orthogonal to business code (I don't want each DAO to explicitly set user ID), to hook into the start of each transaction in order to run a specific SQL statement **before** any other statement in the same transaction.

I need this to work for both implicit transactions (single invocations of `JdbcTemplate`) and transactions demarcated declaratively with Spring's `@Transactional` annotation.

Comment: did you think to use AOP? Or TransactionalEventListener?

Comment: `TransactionalEventListener` does not notify at the start of transaction. The earliest event (or `TransactionPhase`) is `BEFORE_COMMIT`, which is too late in my case, because the triggers have already been executed.
I am considering AOP, namely putting a pointcut on every`JdbcTemplate` method that can write to the database. The advice that would run on these pointcuts would get the current connection, set `autoComit` to `false`, run my special statement and only **afterwards** proceed with the `joinPoint`.  
But this looks like it's going to be very messy and I'm leaving it as last resort.

Comment: This can be implemented on data source level. It's just  required to decorate returned connection. Some data sources provide way to do that. Otherwise it's easy to override getConnection() method. Spring DelegatingDataSource could be used to do that.

Comment: Are you reinventing the wheel? https://javers.org/

Comment: Maybe you may use your own `PlatformTransactionManager` by extending the `DataSourceTransactionManager` and overriding the right methods ( `doBegin`, `doCommit` etc... but I don't know how and if to rightly manage transaction and CRUD operations on temporary tables

Comment: @DoronGold I suppose you should take a look at PlatformTransactionManager and TransactionTemplate in spring-tx.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `JdbcTemplate` does not provide transaction support out-of-the-box (see [here](http://www.javacreed.com/transactions-with-jdbctemplate/)). So, in order to intercept all `@Transaction` annotated code **AND** every call to `JdbcTemplate`, this could be done at DataSource level, as commented earlier by Serge Bogatyrev.

I have a Spring Web project where I tested this approach. I defined a replacement `DataSource` `@Bean` called `MyDataSource` that extends `BasicDataSource`, and overwrites its `getConnection()` method so that it creates the temp table and insert the user_id before returning the connection.

It worked for `@Transaction` calls and pure `JdbcTemplate` calls.

If you want to strictly tie this temp table update **at the start of each transaction**, do this same strategy for defining the `PlatformTransactionManager` `@Bean`. You only need to overwrite the `doBegin()` method. And don't forget to annotate with `@Transaction` all methods calling `JdbcTemplate`.

**PS1**: Make sure to call `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table_name` prior creating the temp table, in order to replace the `DISCARD ALL` on connection returning to pool, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172524/passing-user-id-to-postgresql-triggers/13172964#13172964).

**PS2**: This whole solution of creating a temp table doesn't smell well. I wouldn't implement it myself. I would prefer to take a deep breath and add created_by and updated_by columns to all my tables.

Comment: I am not completely averse to adding `created_by` and `updated_by` columns to each of my tables.
The main thing I'm trying to avoid is littering my DAO methods with boilerplate code that sets and updates these columns. I see this data as orthogonal to business logic and therefore I don't want to completely couple my DAOs with these concerns.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of Spring AOP for setting up the user. The aspect will make a call to the database to set up the application user.

In my example, a stored procedure is used to set up the application user responsible for creating, modifying, or deleting a record . You can customize it according to your requirements. Here is the example aspect which retrieves the `user` from the HTTP request and then makes a call to the stored procedure,

```
@Component
@Aspect
@Slf4j
public class SetUserAspect {

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public SetUserAspect(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Before("execution(* com.basaki.example.service.BookService.*(..) )")
    public void setUser(JoinPoint jp) {
        log.info("In class: " + jp.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName() +
                " - before method: " + jp.getSignature().getName());

        HttpServletRequest request =
                ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        if (request != null) {
            String user = request.getHeader("user");
            if (user != null) {
                log.info("Setting user " + user);
                SimpleJdbcCall
                        jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                        .withSchemaName("example_book_schema")
                        .withFunctionName("set_user");
                SqlParameterSource
                        in =
                        new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("audit_user",
                                user);
                jdbcCall.executeFunction(String.class, in);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All the CRUD operations are performed in `BookService`, essentially a DAO.

Here is the stored procedure used for setting up the user,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION example_book_schema.set_user(
    audit_user TEXT
) RETURNS BOOLEAN STABLE LANGUAGE SQL AS $$
    SELECT set_config('book.audit_user', audit_user, true);
    SELECT TRUE;
```

#### Restricting Pointcuts to Only Transactional Methods

You can restrict the points cuts to only transactional methods in `BookService` by adding an additional clause in the `Before` advice.

```
@Before("execution(* com.basaki.example.service.BookService.*(..) ) " +
            "&& @annotation(annotation)")
    public void setUser(final JoinPoint jp, final Transactional annotation) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The Aspect looks like it would work.
However this assumes that all methods in the DAO are wrapped in a transaction (possibly being annotated with `@Transactional`).
I was trying to avoid this. However, seems like there is not **simple** way around it.

Comment: @DoronGold Please see my updated answer above. You can modify the aspect by adding an additional clause to capture methods with a `@Transactional` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@EntityListeners` to listen change of entity in application context, then collect whatever information (entity value, authentication user, etc...) and then insert to your history table. Example you can follow here: http://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa

Comment: Yes but I guess he is not using JPA and/or Hibernate but pure SQL since he talks about JdbcTemplate

Comment: As @AngeloImmediata correctly pointed, I don't use JPA. So there is no "Entity".

Answer (score 0):

You can create view, add user id column, and use your triggers to deal with updates. So that is yet another way to code it at DB side. That way you are supposed to pass it every time, so no other changes are needed.

Going to Java/Spring side.

A bit oldish style: [TransactionTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html) - that way you have full control, but your dao needs more code, since transaction management needs to be done there.

Other option is to create proxy on 
`org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager` and do your job at `doBegin`, then your proxy needs to be passed to transaction manager. And that is the way to go for me.