# How to get permission to change run-time parameter?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

In this wonderful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13172964/196241) is proposed  GUC-pattern to use run-time parameters to detect current user inside trigger (as one solution). It seemed to suit to me too. But problem is: when I declare the variable in `postgresql.conf` it is usable inside trigger and I can access it from queries, but can't change it:

```
# SET rkdb.current_user = 'xyzaaa';
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "current_user"
LINE 1: SET rkdb.current_user = 'xyzaaa';
```

The error message is misleading, so I did not dig it a while, but now it seems this user (database owner) has no permissions to change params set in global configuration.

I can set any other params:

```
# SET jumala.kama = 24;
SET
```

And read it back:

```
# SHOW jumala.kama;
 jumala.kama 
-------------
 24
(1 row)
```

I can't `SHOW` globally set params:

```
# SHOW rkdb.current_user;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "current_user"
LINE 1: SHOW rkdb.current_user;
                  ^
```

but I can reach it with `current_setting()` function:

```
# select current_setting('rkdb.current_user');
 current_setting 
-----------------
 www
(1 row)
```

So my guess is, my database owner does not have permissions to access this param. How could I:

1. set needed permissions?

or even better

2. set run-time params with database owner rights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current_user` is an SQL standard function, so your use of that name confuses the parser.

Either use a different name or surround it with double quotes like this:

```
rkdb."current_user"
```